# Reverse background and foreground color on BackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am totally new for opencv.js and I am using BackgroundSubtractorMOG2() to substract background.
And my input and output like this:

*Input*:

[image: Input]

*Output*:

[image: Output]

My code:

```
let video = document.getElementById('videoInput');
let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);

let frame = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
let fgmask = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC1);
let fgbg = new cv.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(500, 16, true);

const FPS = 30;
function processVideo() {
    try {
        if (!streaming) {
            // clean and stop.
            frame.delete(); fgmask.delete(); fgbg.delete();
            return;
        }
        let begin = Date.now();
        // start processing.
        cap.read(frame);
        fgbg.apply(frame, fgmask);
        cv.imshow('canvasOutput', fgmask);
        // schedule the next one.
        let delay = 1000/FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
        setTimeout(processVideo, delay);
    } catch (err) {
        utils.printError(err);
    }
};

// schedule the first one.
setTimeout(processVideo, 0);
```

How can i reverse background and foreground colors on fgmask(output2)?I mean "Background color be dark and foreground color be white"

Comment: Finally a question where images make sense. +1 always add the language tag to your questions to target the right audience. added js for you.

Comment: I want to do like this but I can't implement this phyton code on my javascript code: fgmask[np.where((background > [0,0,0]))] =[255,255,255]

Comment: search for opencs + invert  - f,e.  `bitwise_not ( src, dst );` should do what you want. I do not do JS sorry.

Comment: thank you a lot,it works very well

Comment: Consider posting your own answer and accepting in in 48h so other profit :)